# express-handlebars # if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am still pretty new to NodeJS and I am using the express and express-handlebar packages.
However, the 'if-statement' does not work properly, in fact not at all. I suppose the reason for this is that I do not use a template for the if-statement.

Using just the package 'handlebars', I would go with:

```
rs.readFile('files/test.hbs', 'utf-8', function(err, data)
{
 var template = hbs.compile(data);
 var result = template ({name: 'name', value1: 'value1', value2: 'value2'});
 res.end (result);
...
}
```

This solution works actually.

However, I have already used express-handlebars in the entire code and would like to keep on using it. I got following code:

```
//I´ll receive value1 and value2 later either directly from my database or with the help of MQTT
var value1 = ' value1';
var value2 = 'value2';
var name = 'name';
var helpers={
        value1:function(){return value1;},
        value2:function(){return value2;},
        name: function(){return name;}
        }


router.get('/', function(req, res){
          res.render('index', {helpers});
         });
```

My html code looks like following:

```
   <div>
     <h1> {{value1}} </h1>
     <h2> {{value2}} </h2>  
       {{#if name}}
          <h3> hello there! </h3>
       {{/if}}

  </div>
```

value1 and value 2 are shown properly. 'hello there!' isn´t as I suppose it is not a template.
Does anyone know how I can make code work with express-handlebars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered it by myself.
The solution is:

```
      router.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.render('index', {
         name,
         helpers});
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in server.js

```
const isEqual = function(a, b, opts) {
  if (a == b) {
  return opts.fn(this) 
 } else { 
     return opts.inverse(this) 
  } 
 }

 var hbs = require('hbs');
 hbs.registerHelper('if_eq', isEqual);
```